# Nested route: Navigate to named route passing parent params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a nested route like this:

```
  {
    path: '/product/:language',
    name: 'LandingHome',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LandingHome" */ '../views/landings/Base.vue'),
    props:true,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'LandingHome',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LandingHome" */ '../views/landings/Home.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'customers',
        name: 'LandingCustomers',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LandingCustomers" */ '../views/landings/Customers.vue'),
      },
    ]
  },
```

How can i push route to named route "LandingCustomers" but also passing "LandingHome" :language param ?

```
this.$router.push({name: "LandingCustomers", params: { language: locale })
```

As expected language params is passed to child route, but how can push to child and also passing params language to parent on the same time?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

add the `language` in children routes

```
{
    path: '/product',
    name: 'LandingHome',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LandingHome" */ '../views/landings/Base.vue'),
    props:true,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':language',
        name: 'LandingHome',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LandingHome" */ '../views/landings/Home.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: ':language/customers',
        name: 'LandingCustomers',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LandingCustomers" */ '../views/landings/Customers.vue'),
      },
    ]
  },
```

Comment: It's not a best solution because I need to use parent route to set i18n locale in their mount. If I move the params to child I have to replicate this logic on each child view. This is a reason why I want to use params of parent.